# $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\Bbb C\setminus \{0\})$ non- isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(G, \Bbb T)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Do you have an example of an abelian group $G$ for which $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\Bbb C\setminus \{0\})$ is not  isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(G,
 \Bbb T)$?

$\Bbb C$ is the complex plane and $\Bbb T $ is the unit circle group in the complex plane. $\operatorname{Hom}$ denotes homomorphism group.

Comment: What about $G:=\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considered as abstract groups, $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\cong\mathbb{T}$ (both are isomorphic to the direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ of continuum dimension). So $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})\cong\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{T})$ as abstract groups for every $G$.

Comment: Hence the importance of noticing the difference between "isomorphic" and "isomorphic via this particular map I had mind" (presumably the one induced from the inclusion $\mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$)!

Comment: For every abelian $G$!